# How I can make query for below scenario in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have following schema where collection "questionbank" contains "name" attribute and another collection named "question" which contains question_id as id from Question bank collection. It is one too many reationship.

Question Bank:
[Question Bank Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpVM8.png)
Question Collection:

[Question collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjQle.png)

Now I need result where Test_id is "" and for a particular course _id: xyz from question collection but catch here is I need them in sorted order on name field in Question Bank collection.

Please suggest some most efficient and optimize solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly - It sounds like you are looking for a JOIN.

MongoDB doesn't support JOINs.  You will need to manually JOIN the data in your application code using two seperate queries.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/